# powershell more than one operations using pipe

Tags: powershell, pipe, operation

My script looks for all the files in folder1 and checks if this file exist in folder2. if it exists then I want to delete the file from folder2 and move the file from Folder1 to folder3.

```
$folder1 = "D:\folder1"
$folder2= "D:\folder2"
$folder3 = "D:\folder3"

$a = Get-ChildItem $folder1 | select -ExpandProperty basename 

$a | foreach {  
     Get-ChildItem -Path $folder2 -filter *$_* -Recurse 
}
```

Now if I use pipe at the end of for each loop I can either delete or move but not both. How do I handle this situation?

Comment: you can use a semi-colon in the script block to execute multiple commands, so something like this should work: 
$A | foreach { Get-ChildItem -Path $folder2 -filter *$_* -Recurse} | foreach {Remove-Item $_.FullName; Copy-Item $folder1\$_.BaseName $Folder3}

Comment: Thanks. THats the answer i was loking for. can you make this the answer

Comment: no worries, I've posted the answer below, I'd appreciate it if you up vote or select it as the right answer if it has resolved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neither `move-item` or `remove-item` output anything to the pipe. However both have a `-PassThru` switch parameter to allow further processing.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
$A | foreach { Get-ChildItem -Path $folder2 -filter $_ -Recurse} | foreach {Remove-Item $_.FullName; Copy-Item $folder1\$_.BaseName $Folder3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Include(Get-ChildItem -File $folder1) $folder2\* |
foreach { remove-item $_ ; move-item (join-path $folder1 $_.BaseName) -destination $folder3}
```